# Find the number FN with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have one document, and this document has several columns, like this:

```
,Flag2,,Flag4,Flag5,,,,,Flag10,Flag11,Flag12,Flag13
```

If I use awk to know the total number of fields, knowing the separator character is `,` the result is: 13

Now, I want to get the field number for Flag10, the result should be: 10

How can I do this with awk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like below,

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="Flag10")print i}' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo ',Flag2,,Flag4,Flag5,,,,,Flag10,Flag11,Flag12,Flag13' | awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="Flag10")print i}'
10
```

Answer (score 3):

I typically create an associative array, mapping the header names to the column numbers

```
awk -F, -v head="Flag10" '
    FNR == 1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) col[$i] = i}
    {print $col[head]}
' << END
,Flag2,,Flag4,Flag5,,,,,Flag10,Flag11,Flag12,Flag13
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130
END
```

```
Flag10
100
```

Answer (score 3):

To use `awk` builtin's:

```
awk -F, -v field="Flag10" '{sub(field",.*",field);print split($0,any)}' doc.file
```

The script will remove everything after the first occurrence of the value of `field` (in this case, `Flag10`) and then print the result of splitting the line on commas. Since we've deleted everything after `Flag10`, this results in the number of fields left which is the field number of the search pattern.